# Angular build Error genMapping.encodedMap is not a function

Tags: node.js, angular13

I am facing a new error while trying to run my Angular 13 version project locally.
This happened after I installed Node js 16.6 yesterday.

This is the first line of the error:

```
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build- 
angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
 TypeError: genMapping.encodedMap is not a function
```

Here is further details of the error dump:

```
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build- 
angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: genMapping.encodedMap is not a function
at new SourceMap (C:\BreakPack\temp\breakpack-manager- 
ui\node_modules\@ampproject\remapping\dist\remapping.umd.js:169:91)
at remapping (C:\BreakPack\temp\breakpack-manager- 
ui\node_modules\@ampproject\remapping\dist\remapping.umd.js:203:16)
at Object.result (C:\BreakPack\temp\breakpack-manager-ui\node_modules\@angular- 
devkit\build-angular\src\babel\webpack-loader.js:210:48)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\BreakPack\temp\breakpack-manager-ui\node_modules\babel- 
loader\lib\index.js:221:43)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\BreakPack\temp\breakpack-manager-ui\node_modules\babel- 
 loader\lib\index.js:3:103)
at _next (C:\BreakPack\temp\breakpack-manager-ui\node_modules\babel- 
loader\lib\index.js:5:194)
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong or what I need to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: I've got this error in another project that uses `@ampproject/remapping@2.2.0` indirectly, as a dependency of `@babel/core@7.19.1`.

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't helpful, but the reason it happens is because a package in your `node_modules` (`@jridgewell/gen-mapping`) is missing. which could be for a number of reason like installation errors, symlinking dependencies in certain ways, etc.

More details: https://github.com/ampproject/remapping/issues/180

To fix the issue, double check that your dependencies are properly installed, and that the particular package is present in `node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same issue, when we build our application in Docker. The problem was a node version mismatch.

A solution could be to just delete your node_modules folder and reinstall.

We are using node 14.21.3, and this works fine.